# Как сдвинуть область для ввода текста в input?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Вот такая проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сдвинуть область для ввода текста в `<input>`, а заодно и `placeholder`, чтобы ввод текста начинался после иконки?

```css
.search {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 31px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #24356f;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.search_div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 8px;
}

.search input[type=text] {
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.search input[type=submit] {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search_div">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20/000000/ffffff">

    <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Товары для стоматологии" />

    <input type="submit" size="10" value="Найти" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: padding для input задать?

Comment: @sergey-dev генеально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.search input[type=text]{
    padding-left: 24px;
    height:24px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.search {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 31px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #24356f;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.search_div img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 8px;
}

.search input[type=text] {
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.search input[type=submit] {
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search_div">
    <img src="images/Search.png" >
    <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Товары для стоматологии"/>
    <input type="submit" size="10" value="Найти" />
  </div>
</div>
```